# Target a :target::before on flex-element does not work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In several designs, I have `position:fixed` nav-bar.

A problem rises when I clic on an anchor in the page. The page scrolls to the `:target`(ed) element.
Because of the fixed navbar, the target is partially hidden (*Link1* in the codepen)

As workaround, I use a `:target::before` that I push above the `:target`. As a result when I clic on the anchor, the page scrolls to the `:target::before`: the :target gets pushed down a bit and is not covered by the navbar. (*link2* in the codepen).

This works well… except if the anchored element is flexible (with display:flex).

No matter what I try, when I clic on the anchor, the page scrolls to the flexbox, not it’s `::before`.

I can I do prevent that?

Link : https://codepen.io/lehollandaisvolant/pen/JOOQeq

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some extensive trial, I used this on a parent box. The parentbox must have the #id so that the actual box is pushed down under the nav-bar :

```
padding-top: 100px;
margin-top: -100px;
```

It’s not ideal, but it does the job.